# Get src value from bean class in iframe (Dialog not being updated)

Tags: iframe, primefaces

My code is below:

```
<p:commandButton value="test" action="#{myProgram1.test1}" oncomplete="ex2.show()"/>

<p:dialog id="dialog2"  widgetVar="ex2"   onShow="jQuery('#someId').show();">
            <iframe frameborder="0" align="left"
                    src="#{myProgram1.url}"
                    name="someName" id="someId" scrolling="auto" width="750"
                    height="500">
            </iframe>
</p:dialog>
```

I have set the value of url in test1 method. But it's not loading the url from bean class. But if I specify particular url then it is opening.

Comment: Did you check that the `getUrl()` is called after `test1()`? Had a similar problem and the url was not set at the correct time (meaning before getter being called)

Answer (score 2):

Add `update="dialog2"` to your `<p:commandButton`

So it will look like this :

```
<p:commandButton value="test" update="dialog2" 
     action="#{myProgram1.test1}" oncomplete="ex2.show()"/>
```